# Bad query plan with query using CTE and scalar functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I have a poorly performing query on a very large table that uses a CTE to narrow down the results.  The CTE results in three rows max and is produced by getting a max aggregate value from the source table and then using CROSS APPLY and scalar functions to produce the desired columns.

Interestingly, if I load the data from the CTE into a table variable and join the table variable to my source table then the performance of the query improves quite dramatically.

The query plans are very different:

- The CTE version has one Nested Loops join which specifies "Warning: No Join Predicate."  It then has a filter that follows using what I feel should be the join predicate.
- The Table Variable version has two Nested Loops joins and no Filter operation.

What would be the way to fix this so I could just use the CTE - maybe a query or join hint of some sort?

```
-- table variable for alt version of query
-- DECLARE @PeriodsTbl TABLE (PeriodCode varchar(10), PeriodDate date, PeriodDateKey int);

WITH PeriodsSource AS (
    SELECT forPeriods.*, forPeriodDateKeys.*
    FROM (SELECT dbo.DateKeyToDate(MAX(EndDateKey)) MaxDate FROM BigTable) forMaxDate
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT x.*, dbo.DateToDatekey(x.PeriodDate) PeriodDateKey
        FROM ( VALUES
            ( 'cur', CAST(MaxDate AS DATE) )
            , ( 'pw', CAST(DATEADD(day, -7, MaxDate) AS DATE) )
            , ( 'py', CAST(DATEADD(day, -364, MaxDate) AS DATE) )
        ) x ( PeriodCode, PeriodDate )
    ) forPeriods
)
--INSERT INTO @PeriodsTbl 
--SELECT PeriodCode, PeriodDate, PeriodDateKey 
--FROM PeriodsSource ps;
SELECT *
FROM PeriodsSource ps -- Use @PeriodsTbl For Table Version
INNER JOIN BigTable bt ON bt.StartDateKey <= ps.PeriodDateKey 
    AND bt.EndDateKey >= ps.PeriodDateKey
```

Comment: From a performance perspective those scalar functions are low hanging fruit. They are notoriously terrible from a performance standpoint. Changing those to inline table valued functions would be a great first step.

Comment: @SeanLange hit the nail on the head, but it'd also help to know your indexes for each table.

Comment: @SeanLange, taking the function out of the `forMaxDate` table and moving it to the expression that creates PeriodDate made the problem go away - Now the query plan looks very similar to the Table Variable plan.  So...  why?

Comment: Table variables usually don't perform well either because it's a variable and thus, is expected to return 1 value. The statistics on the table variable will expect 1 row returned... so if you are stuffing a ton of rows in there, the execution plan can suffer since it doesn't expect this and thus may choose the wrong options (memory grants, etc) to complete your query.

Comment: @SeanLange comment would make the most difference, and he's smarter than I, so I'll encourage him to answer :)

Comment: @DanielGimenez, your BigTable bt can also do with a change in the 'ON' clause as ps.PeriodDateKey  between bt.StartDateKey AND bt.EndDateKey

Comment: @scsimon ROFL. Definitely not smarter than you, unless perhaps you mean smart aleck. :) I can throw up an answer suggesting to remove the scalar functions. But honestly I just happened in here earlier than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the performance problems are because of the liberal use of scalar functions. They are routinely terrible from a performance perspective. Converting those to an inline table valued function would be my first step. Make sure they are NOT multi-statement table valued functions though or you might actually end up going backwards for performance. Or if the function is fairly simple you could just inline the logic which will be even better.

**EDIT**

Using a *scalar function in the join* caused the plan to change from a more efficient one to one joining without a predicate and filtering after.  `PeriodDateKey` is produced in the CTE from the function `DateToDatekey` and that is what is being joined to BigTable.  Changing it to a functionally equivalent expression caused the plan to change and produced a big improvement.

Trying to move the function call outside of the CROSS APPLY produced no improvement and while removing all references to scalar functions produced a performance gain, it was not as significant as the gain realized by the one change to `PeriodDateKey`